# Album art for "Abraxas" (Santana) and "Bitches Brew" (Miles Davis)

Tags: artwork

Looking at the album art (below) for [*Abraxas*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abraxas_%28album%29) by Santana and [*Bitches Brew*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitches_Brew) by Miles Davis. Is there a commmon theme going on here? Specifically the African tribal people on the back covers?

It looks to me like either these people are representing a theme, the same artist did both covers, or some artistic theft has gone on.

Can anyone shed any light on this?

**EDIT**

It turns out that the artist for both album covers was [Mati Klarwein](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mati_Klarwein#1970s) which explains the style and the reproduction of the people.

But, the question remains, who do they represent (either as a theme or as a people)?

> [image: Abraxas album cover art]
>
> [image: Bitches Brew album cover art]

Answer (score 4):

Well, Santana was influenced by Hispanic tradition. It's pretty straightforward. Bitches Brew, however, is different. Miles Davis started experimenting with improvisation and full rhythm sections. It explains the tribal and soulful feel of the album.

Answer (score 1):

The tribe that is depicted are the men of the Wodaabe tribe. I am uncertain why they were used or what the meaning is, I’m trying to see if a reference was ever made on why their imagery was chosen.

Comment: How do you know it's that tribe?